# How to get all column from Realm's DB table?

Tags: android, realm

I know that question is stupid, but I need to create Spinner using Realm and get one column for this.

All I want is get one all columt to String array to use ArrayAdapter.

How can I get this column?

Or maybe the better way is extend ArrayAdapter where I will get all rows from that column using a loop?

Tell me, please, the better solution.

Comment: Fetch the objects and read their fields?

Comment: Did you mean I need to use findAll() than use a loop and than get what I need? I'm just dreaming about some easy function like "getNeededColumn(<class>,"columnName")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are special Adapters for Realm:

- Documentation: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#adapters
- Project-Page: https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters
- Example-Code: https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/adapters/ui/listview/MyListAdapter.java

---

Example code:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<TimeStamp> implements ListAdapter {

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView timestamp;
    }

    public MyListAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<TimeStamp> realmResults) {
        super(realmResults);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.timestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        TimeStamp item = adapterData.get(position);
        viewHolder.timestamp.setText(item.getTimeStamp());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this repository is using for UI, not for simple String[] or whatever simple thing

Comment: @AlexSmith why are you so desperately trying to create a less performant solution, that doesn't even listen to automatic updates - and read **all** data before you actually need it (rather than lazy-load it)?

Comment: Creating my own adapter is the one of the variants what I suppose to do. I dont want to use ready-made solution like you offered. Primarily I'm studying, that's all

Comment: @EpicPandaForce did you think I make better use your solution?

Comment: @AlexSmith well if you want to reinvent the wheel, then I definitely vote against using an `ArrayAdapter`. Just because you're learning, doesn't mean you should do things that don't really make sense. Hold on :P

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Your words warm my soul :D Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to reinvent the wheel, then you should avoid `ArrayAdapter` in the first place. After all, it handles the actual binding between your elements and your views, which means you learn less!

So if you want to learn, you should create a `BaseAdapter`. With this, we'll recreate the `RealmBaseAdapter`.

Okay, so how it works is that you can extend `BaseAdapter` which expects the following methods:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // return item at position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // return unique identifier at position index
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // implement view holder pattern
        // bind view holder with data at position
        // return bound view
    }
}
```

---

---

And a `RealmBaseAdapter` also gives you a `RealmChangeListener` that is appended to a `RealmResults` that you provide on creation.

So your case would look like this

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    RealmResults<YourObject> results;

    final RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(Object element) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    public YourAdapter(RealmResults<YourObject> results) {
        this.results = results;
        results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    public void updateData(RealmResults<YourObject> results) {
        if(this.results.isValid()) {
            this.results.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        }
        this.results = results;
        results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // return count;
        if(results == null || !results.isValid()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return results.size();
    }

    @Override
    public YourObject getItem(int position) {
        // return item at position;
        return results.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // return unique identifier at position index
        return position; // this is sufficient
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {        
        // implement view holder pattern
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }    

        // bind view holder with data at position
        YourObject item = results.get(position);
        viewHolder.textView.setText(item.getNeededColumn());

        // return bound view
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(realm.where(YourObject.class).findAll());
listView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

---

Although I kinda prefer RecyclerViews lately, but that's ok

Comment: Oh, that is so beautifull! Thank you very much!